# Set data value in rules not written when using a condition

Tags: rules

I like to create a rule that will overwrite my body field after saving new content. This is content from the same node that has been created(field_update) and some content from referenced users form a user reference field(field_userrefer).

I have a CUSTOM TEXT field called "field_update". 
This is is were content is written.

My actionrule is :

- set data value "node-body-value" to
- [node:field-update]
  this works.

I have to create conditions to get the required fields I want to show in the data selection.
This also works very nice because is can see all fields in my data selection auto complete box.

The problem is that when I add these conditions my body field isn't being populated by my custom values.

Any help appreciated.

When i have a set of rules without conditions.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your Rule's config screen? Or/And even better your exported rule?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed. Seems like conditions is quite the puzzle. I fetched entity by ID with actions to fix it.

conditions: 
Entity has field: parameter:node, Field:field_userref

actions:
Fetch entity by id(id01) :. type: user, id:node:field-userref:uid
Fetch entity by id(id02) :. type: profile, id:entity-id01:profile-main:pid
wich made all profile2 fields available.